# Redirect information to specific place in file

Tags: batch-file

I need to be able to redirect information to the top row of another file, is this possible or do you need to solve the problem in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the trick 
use a temp file, write your info, append the previous logfile and rename tempfile to overwrite the previous one

```
echo %yourinfo%> c:\temp\temp.txt
type c:\temp\logfile.txt >> c:\temp\temp.txt
ren c:\temp\temp.txt c:\temp\logfile.txt
```

Comment: that's really smart! I would never have thought of that!